# Firestore database not connecting with Firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, backend

I am trying to retrieve Firestore database information through Express.js used in Firebase cloud functions. My index.js files inside the function folder look like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();
admin.initializeApp();
const express = require('express');
const app= express();

app.get("/teacher/:uid",function(req,res){
    const id = req.params.uid;
    const doc = db.collection('users').doc(id).get();
    res.send(doc);
    //res.render("teacher",{id : id});
})
```

the script part of my index.html file looks like:

```
<body>

// some html code 
<!---script follow-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>
<script>
  // web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xyz",
    authDomain: "xyz",
    databaseURL: "xyz",
    projectId: "xyz",
    appId: "xyz"
  };
  // i have replaced the actual keys and urls with xyz

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth= firebase.auth();
  const db= firebase.firestore();
  const functions = firebase.functions();

</script>

<script src="auth.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
ERROR : 
on command firebase serve --only functions , i am getting this error 

 Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:123:28)
    at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.app (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:101:19)
    at FirebaseNamespace.app (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:452:30)
    at FirebaseNamespace.ensureApp (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:468:24)
    at Proxy.fn (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:327:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chahat/Desktop/firebase/functions/index.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

Comment: Hello, can you share the `auth.js` file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several parts that you should change in your Cloud Function code:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require("firebase-admin");
 admin.initializeApp();

 const db = admin.firestore();   //#1

 const express = require('express');
 const app= express();

 app.get("/teacher/:uid",function(req, res){
    const id = req.params.uid;
    db.collection('users').doc(id).get()   //#2  
    .then(snap => {
        res.send(snap.data());
    })
    .catch(error => {...})
 })
```

1. Define Firestore as `admin.firestore()` **after** having initialized the Admin SDK.
2. The `get()` method is asynchronous. You need to wait for the Promise its returns to resolve before being able to return the response. More details in the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series

Comment: thankyou , i have shared the auth.js file and error as my answer.

Comment: Please add the content in your initial question and not by creating an anwser. You can edit your initial question. For the moment it is not clear how are your front-end and your Cloud Function related to each other. You may have a look at this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions. Also, from the error you get it seems you have a problem of Node.js version.